# Network Connection State on BgInfo

Tags: vbscript, wmi

Is there a vbs script or WBI that will show the status of a network adapter such as 'Disconnected', "Connected", 'Authenticating', etc in BgInfo?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With BgInfo you can call WMI. So if you look at Win32_NetworkAdapter and grab NetConnectionStatus you get a number. This number represents your current state. See the list below.

You can get more ideas and script sources from [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/08/how-do-i-find-information-about-the-network-adapter-cards-on-my-computer.aspx) and [here](http://forum.sysinternals.com/custom-field-for-nic-connection-speed_topic28854.html).

[image]

So if you search WMI for your network card you can get something like this. (Note I am using PowerShell as I don't have BgInfo.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter -Filter {ProductName = 'Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection'} | select NetConnectionStatus

NetConnectionStatus
-------------------
                  2
```

So at least in PowerShell you can have something like this.

```
$ConnectionStatus = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter -Filter {ProductName = 'Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection'} | select -expand NetConnectionStatus
switch ($ConnectionStatus)
    {
        0 {"Disconnected"}
        1 {"Connecting"}
        2 {"Connected"}
        3 {"Disconnecting"}
        4 {"Hardware not present"}
        5 {"Hardware disabled"}
        6 {"Hardware malfunction"}
        7 {"Media disconnected"}
        8 {"Authenticating"}
        9 {"Authentication succeeded"}
        10 {"Authentication failed"}
        11 {"Invalid address"}
        12 {"Credentials required"}
        default {"Connection unknown"}
    }
```

My VB is way to rusty to be able to knock that out quickly in it.

Comment: Thank you.
Is there a way to modify the 2 so that it display 'Connected'?

Comment: @cynflux I added a code example.